# Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BadRequestException: ResourceType Document is unexpected

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to update a specific product in my database.I pass the product value from body and replace it .here my partition key is catlog id.blow i give alll my code example please tell me what did i wrong?

Json body:

```html
{
    "id": "9fc41e97-c32e-45e6-853f-ae7993cbc773",
    "VendorName": "string",
    "Industy": {
        "Id": "40f5a6f5-2947-469c-8d29-6aa84de982cb",
        "IdustryId": 0,
        "IdustryName": "string",
        "Category": {
            "id": "bf16c9a1-52c6-4e88-b24a-082591718ece",
            "Name": "string",
            "Description": "string",
            "Subcategory": {
                "id": "c60a191a-f5b8-4cff-8926-e4b364f8aba2",
                "Name": "string",
                "Description": "string",
                "Product": {
                    "Id": "97c27069-4a16-44c3-bdf1-627c8ea339fa",
                    "Name": "string",
                    "CurrentQuantity": 0,
                    "Tag": "string",
                    "Unit": "string",
                    "Price": 0,
                    "hasMethodOfPreparation": true,
                    "Addons": {
                        "id": "1b7afbc0-36df-4a97-951e-4f0fef0c683f",
                        "Description": "string",
                        "Price": 0
                    },
                    "MethodOfPreparation": {
                        "id": "9e1581cf-8401-44c0-ac8b-15e972276178",
                        "Description": "string",
                        "Price": 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Controller code:

```html
  [HttpPut("UpdateProductByIdAsync/{id}", Name = "UpdateProductById")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateProductByIdAsync(
           [FromRoute] Guid id,
           [FromBody] Product order)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id == null
                || id == Guid.Empty)
            {
                return BadRequest("Id required.");
            }

            order.Id = id;
        
            var result =
                await _catalogRepository.UpdateProductByIdAsync(
                    id,
                    order);

            return Ok(result);
        }
```

Reposito

```html
  public async Task<Catalog> UpdateProductByIdAsync(
           Guid id,
           Product order)
        {
            
            var requestOptions =
               new RequestOptions
               {
                   PartitionKey = new Microsoft.Azure.Documents.PartitionKey(id.ToString())
               };


            var catalogDocument = await _cosmosClient.ReplaceDocumentAsync(
                 UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(
                     _azureCosmosDbOptions.Value.DatabaseId, "catalog"), order, requestOptions);
           
            return
                (Catalog)((dynamic)catalogDocument.Resource);
        }

       
    }
```

Error:

```html
 <pre class="rawExceptionStackTrace">Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BadRequestException: ResourceType Document is unexpected.&#xD;&#xA;ActivityId: 62f61852-d2a7-466a-9765-80db1d02de32, Windows/10.0.17134 documentdb-netcore-sdk/2.4.0&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.PathsHelper.GeneratePathForNameBased(ResourceType resourceType, String resourceFullName, Boolean isFeed, Boolean notRequireValidation)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.GatewayStoreModel.GetEntityUri(DocumentServiceRequest entity)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.GatewayStoreModel.ProcessMessageAsync(DocumentServiceRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.ProcessRequestAsync(DocumentServiceRequest request, IDocumentClientRetryPolicy retryPolicyInstance, CancellationToken cancellationToken)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.ReplaceDocumentPrivateAsync(String documentLink, Document document, RequestOptions options, IDocumentClientRetryPolicy retryPolicyInstance, CancellationToken cancellationToken)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.ExecuteRetryAsync(Func`1 callbackMethod, Func`3 callShouldRetry, Func`1 inBackoffAlternateCallbackMethod, TimeSpan minBackoffForInBackoffCallback, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Action`1 preRetryCallback)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ShouldRetryResult.ThrowIfDoneTrying(ExceptionDispatchInfo capturedException)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.ExecuteRetryAsync(Func`1 callbackMethod, Func`3 callShouldRetry, Func`1 inBackoffAlternateCallbackMethod, TimeSpan minBackoffForInBackoffCallback, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Action`1 preRetryCallback)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.ReplaceDocumentInlineAsync(String documentLink, Object document, RequestOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)&#xD;&#xA;   at CatalogAPI.Services.CatalogRepository.UpdateProductByIdAsync(Guid id, Product order) in D:\UCDP\UCDP\UCDP\src\Service\Catalog\CatalogAPI\Services\CatalogRepository.cs:line 322&#xD;&#xA;   at CatalogAPI.Controllers.CatalogController.UpdateProductByIdAsync(Guid id, Product order) in D:\UCDP\UCDP\UCDP\src\Service\Catalog\CatalogAPI\Controllers\CatalogController.cs:line 158&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&amp; next, Scope&amp; scope, Object&amp; state, Boolean&amp; isCompleted)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State&amp; next, Scope&amp; scope, Object&amp; state, Boolean&amp; isCompleted)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)&#xD;&#xA;   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)&#xD;&#xA;   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)&#xD;&#xA;   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)</pre>
```

Please help me to do this task .I tried the upsertDocumentAsync but creating a new document file rather than updating the exiting one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did like blow:

```html
  public async Task<Catalog> UpdateProductIdAsync(
          Guid productid,
          Product productData)
        {

            var feedOptions =
               new FeedOptions
               {
                   MaxItemCount = -1,
                   EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true
               };

            var query =
                $"SELECT catalog.id,catalog.VendorName,catalog.Industy FROM catalog join industry in catalog.Industy join category in industry.Category join product in category.Subcategory.Product where product.Id ='" + productid + "'";

            var catlog = _cosmosClient.CreateDocumentQuery<Catalog>(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(
            _azureCosmosDbOptions.Value.DatabaseId, "catalog"), query, feedOptions).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();


            if (catlog != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in catlog.Industy)
                {
                    foreach (var cat in item.Category)
                    {
                       Product product = cat.Subcategory.Product.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == productid);
                        if (product != null)
                        {
                            product.Name = productData.Name == null ? product.Name : productData.Name;
                            product.Addons = productData.Addons == null ? product.Addons : productData.Addons;
                            product.CurrentQuantity = productData.CurrentQuantity == null ? product.CurrentQuantity : productData.CurrentQuantity;
                            product.MethodOfPreparation = productData.MethodOfPreparation == null ? product.MethodOfPreparation : productData.MethodOfPreparation;
                            product.Price = productData.Price == null ? product.Price : productData.Price;
                            product.Tag = productData.Tag == null ? product.Tag : productData.Tag;
                            product.Unit = productData.Unit == null ? product.Unit : productData.Unit;
                            product.hasMethodOfPreparation = productData.hasMethodOfPreparation == false ? product.hasMethodOfPreparation : productData.hasMethodOfPreparation;
   
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }

            var requestOptions =
              new RequestOptions
              {
                  PartitionKey = new Microsoft.Azure.Documents.PartitionKey(catlog.Id.ToString())
              };

            var orderDocument = await _cosmosClient.ReplaceDocumentAsync(
                 UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(
                     _azureCosmosDbOptions.Value.DatabaseId, "catalog", catlog.Id.ToString()), catlog, requestOptions);

            return
            (Catalog)((dynamic)catlog);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call **`ReplaceDocumentAsync`** you need to provide the **`Collection Uri`**.

The assignment should look like this:

```
_collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseName, CollectionName);
```

Answer (score 2):

[ReplaceDocumentAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.replacedocumentasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_DocumentClient_ReplaceDocumentAsync_System_String_System_Object_Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_RequestOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) calls need the Document Uri, not the DocumentCollection.

```
var catalogDocument = await _cosmosClient.ReplaceDocumentAsync(
             UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(
                 _azureCosmosDbOptions.Value.DatabaseId, "catalog", order.Id), order, requestOptions);
```

Comment: This is easy to overlook as `UpsertDocumentAsync` does require the Collection URI.